# How to pass a variable to an sh child process?

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “send” variable to sub-shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23179/how-to-send-variable-to-sub-shell)

I have a `bash` script and inside that script I do `sh`. How to pass a variable to the new shell? This is how it is (simplified to the specific problem):

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#......
MYVAR=myvalue
sh -c 'some_code_here'
#......
```

Basically I want to use the `MYVAR` in my `some_code_here` part. I am thinking of creating a temp script and executing it. But if there's a simple way to pass, I can avoid temp script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just `export` it:

```
#!/bin/bash

export MYVAR=myvalue
sh -c 'some_code_here'
```

Comment: Thx. But `export` didn't work as I do sudo and run the script in the background(&) which goes into another shell. My mistake, I should have given the whole picture. Anyway, one other answer from the dup link posted worked.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid needing special shell syntax and avoid problems with things like `sudo`, use `env`:

```
env MYVAR=value sh -c "blah"
```