# How to export variable for use with sudo?

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

On Slackware, using `sbopkg` permits one to build a package from source. Repos is not big as Debian, but it's nice.

Some software can use environment variables,
for example on the VICE c64 emulator, if the variable
`FFMPEG` is set to `yes`, it will enable `ffmpeg` recording the emulator.

I tried to use

```
$ export FFMPEG=yes; sudo sbopkg -B -i vice
```

but `ffmpeg` is disabled.

Instead I had to use

```
$ su -
$ export FFMPEG=yes
$ sbopkg -B -i vice
```

which works.

How to use environment variables with `sudo`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You may use sudo's `-E` option:

```
FMPEG=yes sudo -E sbopkg -B -i vice
```

From the manual:

> -E, --preserve-env
>
> Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to
>   preserve their existing environment variables. The security
>   policy may return an error if the user does not have permission
>   to preserve the environment.

Note that this exports **all** your existing environment variables. **It is safer to only export the environment variables you need with the following syntax**:

**`sudo FMPEG=yes sbopkg -B -i vice`**

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work(the .-E option) the other line is ok so because first answer i select as correct.

Answer (score 15):

`sudo` sanitizes the variables in the environment before invoking the given command.  You will have to ask it to preserve the variables in the environment for your command to work.

Additionally, you will have to `export` the `FMPEG` variable before using `sudo` (`export FMPEG=yes; sudo`), assign it in the same go as invoking `sudo` (`FMPEG=yes sudo`), or use `env` (`env FMPEG=yes sudo`).

To preserve the environment variables, use `-E` (or `--preserve-env`):

```
$ env FMPEG=yes sudo -E sbopkg -B -i vice
```

It's also possible to set specific environment variables like this:

```
$ sudo FMPEG=yes sbopkg -B -i vice
```

If this fails due to the security policy in place, bring up a root shell and set the variable there:

```
$ sudo -s
# env FMPEG=yes sbopkg -B -i vice
# exit
```

Answer (score 8):

note that:
`(export a=b; command)` is equivalent to `a=b command`. Note the brackets.

Then if we apply the variable not to `sudo` but direct to `sbopkg`,
so instead of `FFMPEG=yes sudo sbopkg -B -i vice` 
we can do
`sudo FFMPEG=yes sbopkg -B -i vice`

If a security police prevent this, then:
`sudo bash -c "FFMPEG=yes sbopkg -B -i vice"`

(Don't use `-E`, it us insecure as it will leak all sorts of unexpected variables.)